# Why is google.script.run.myFunction() not working in HTML in App Scripts

Tags: html, google-apps-script, google-sheets

My File API_Render.gs

```
//Made By Aiden Conklin
//Made on March 16, 2023 @ 4:39 pm 
//Last Modified on March 17,2023 @ 12:06pm
var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi()
function getCanvasInfoAPI(Token) {
  try{
  var Data = UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://canvas.instructure.com/api/v1/courses?access_token='+Token);
  var Status = Data.getResponseCode();
  Logger.log("Status: %s\n Data: %s",Status,Data)
  }catch(err){
    console.error('getCanvasInfoAPI() yielded an error: ' + err);
  }}
  function setPort(formObject){
     var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet2"); 
  sheet.appendRow([formObject.token]);
  ui.alert([formObject.token]);//This is to show that the function ran.
  }
  async function RequestToken(){
    ui.showSidebar(HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('API Request Form').setTitle("Token Request"))
    
  }
```

My HTML: API Request Form:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <base target="_top">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ssl.gstatic.com/docs/script/css/add-ons1.css">
</head>

<body>
  <!-- input control to add comment -->
  <form id="token" onsubmit=checkData(this)>
    <fieldset>
      <legend>Enter Your Token</legend>
      <br>
      <input type="text" name="token" value="" placeholder="Enter your Token here">
      <br>
      <br>
      <input type="submit" value="Submit">
      <input type="reset" value="Cancel">
    </fieldset>
  </form>

  <script>
    function checkData(form) {
      var t=0;
      if (form.token.value != "") {
        google.script.run.setPort(form);
        t+=1;
      }
      if(1==t){google.script.host.close()}
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

The only thing I can tell is that in the log it says the program has been completed
GOAL: I want it so that when the person adds its Token it will run Function setPort()

I've tried Utilities.sleep(2000), but if you don't enter your Token within a certian timeframe it will not run setPort()

Answer (score 0):

#### Modification points:

- In your showing script, `<form id="token" onsubmit=checkData(this)>` might be `<form id="token" onsubmit="checkData(this);return false;">`.
- `google.script.run` is run with the asynchronous process. I think that this might be the reason for your current issue. In this case, `withSuccessHandler` is used after the function `setPort` was finished.

When these points are reflected in your script, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

In this modification, your HTML is modified. In this case, your Google Apps Script is not modified.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <base target="_top">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ssl.gstatic.com/docs/script/css/add-ons1.css">
</head>

<body>
  <!-- input control to add comment -->
  <form id="token" onsubmit="checkData(this);return false;">
    <fieldset>
      <legend>Enter Your Token</legend>
      <br>
      <input type="text" name="token" value="" placeholder="Enter your Token here">
      <br>
      <br>
      <input type="submit" value="Submit">
      <input type="reset" value="Cancel">
    </fieldset>
  </form>

  <script>
    function checkData(form) {
      if (form.token.value != "") {
        google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(google.script.host.close).setPort(form);
      }
    }
  </script>
</body>
```

- When this HTML is opened, when you put a value to the input tag and click the "Submit" button, `checkData` is run and `setPort` at Google Apps Script is run, and then, `withSuccessHandler(google.script.host.close)` is run.

#### Reference:

- [Class google.script.run (Client-side API)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run)

Comment: Thank you this worked and I will use a modified reference to you in my code.